# webgl strange rendering artifacts

Tags: webgl

**UPDATE:**
I have posted the code online to demonstrate the issue:
http://cutama.github.io/

To see the problem, position the mouse on the red rectangle and zoom in and out using the mouse scroller. After a while you will see the triangles flickering, then use the left mouse button to rotate.

Controls:

left mouse click&drag: orbit, middle mouse click&drag: pan, mouse scroll: zoom

**END UPDATE**

I have encountered a strange rendering problem with webgl. Whenever I moved the camera around, some triangles appear to be missing randomly. See pictures below.
I have been digging around but could not find the cause. Any ideas what may be causing this?

This is the normal rendering of the geometry:
[image]

Missing triangles:
[image]

Another missing triangles:
[image]

Did some debugging with webgl inspector.

GL Trace:
[image]

Clicking on the missing pixel show that it is being depth culled, but nothing is in front of it...so why is it culled?
[image]

Comparison with normal unculled pixel:
[image]

Vertex data inside the buffer. The triangles are very small. Is this causing the problem?
[image]

Comment: Hard to say. I think you have to either provide some code or provide a live demo.

Comment: I added some trace from webgl inspector. The missing triangles are being depth discarded, but no other triangle is over it.

Comment: Code would really help debug this. Take your app, stub out everything not necessary to demonstrate the bug to produce a short program, and post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue is caused by incorrect triangle indices in the model..still not sure why it would cause flickering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what makes this bug. But, I will list what you might need to consider.

- Check you specified correct PrimitiveTopology(It should be gl.TRIANGLES in many case)
- Check you rendered wether gl.DrawElements or gl.DrawArrays. 
  If you are using index buffer, you should use gl.DrawElements
- Check you are using correct culling configuration.
- Check you are using correct depth comparing function.(If you are not using depth test,you don't need to care about this)

Comment: Thanks. I believe I am doing all these correctly. I have posted a demo code online (see update on the main post) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong in your code. But, I think you should show a piece of code that is rendering this scene.
Or you can try these things below to identify what is wrong.
* Draw them with wire frame
* Try to draw the other models

Comment: I have tried with other models, and only this one is having the problem. Looks like something is wrong with the data, that is what I want to find out.